# I need to have my 2 websites to have an individual rDNS record but they both are running on the shared web hosting servers

Tags: vps, reverse-dns, dedicated-server, shared-hosting

I'm a server noob and want to get some solution or some advice from the gurus of the ServerFault.
I currently have two different live websites running and they both are using the shared web hosting servers. But I need to have those two websites to have an individual rDNS record set up for each and to work that out, it seems like I need to have those two websites migrate to two different dedicated servers since I would need two different dedicated IP addresses? Those two websites are small in size and it seems like it's kind of a waste for me in terms of charge of money and space to have two dedicated servers for those two small websites and what I want to ask is that **is it technically possible to have two different individual dedicated IP addresses for each website using VPS for alternative solution? and would that be recommended for me?**

ps: The reason why I need to set up a rDNS record for each website is that I'm facing a problem that one of my websites' emails are getting blocked by Gmail and seems like I need to get rDNS set up for those to lessen the probability to get those mails marked as spam.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are VPS providers that allow you to assign multiple IPs on a single VPS, and a rDNS on each.

However, I recommend using an email service provider, who provides you with infrastructure for email and takes care of reliable delivery.